# -[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:] throws weird error when calling shared instance of JSContext

Tags: objective-c, runtime-error, webkit, nsurlsession, theos

I am trying to execute JavaScript in a hooked method from the NSURLSession class (cluster) which returns a LocalDataTask. For some reason my iOS tweak causes apps to crash when they call the method that I've hooked (-[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:]) using Theos.

I have no idea why this is happening because I am not getting any useful error messages.

The reason why I am grabbing the JSContext from a UIWebView is because I want to make use of all the JavaScript objects from WebKit (e.g. XMLHttpRequest).

I have the following code in my Tweak.xm file:

```c
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

@interface myJSContext : NSObject
+(JSContext *)sharedContext;
@end

@implementation myJSContext

+(JSContext *)sharedContext {
  static JSContext * jsCtxt = nil;
  static UIWebView * webView = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  if (!webView) {
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      webView = [[%c(UIWebView) alloc] init];
      jsCtxt = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
    });
  }
  return jsCtxt;
}

@end

%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)arg1 {
  %orig;
  NSLog(@"%@", [myJSContext sharedContext]); // prints the pointer as expected
  NSLog(@"%@", [[myJSContext sharedContext] evaluateScript:@"'js test result'.toString()"]); // successfully executes JavaScript as expected
}

%end

%hook NSURLSession

-(id)dataTaskWithRequest:(id)arg1 {
  NSLog(@"%@", [myJSContext sharedContext]); // this causes an error, I've tried calling this from the main and global thread which didn't work either
  return %orig;
}

%end
```

I don't see any useful error messages, but I will include the logs of potential relevance.

EDIT: I cannot post all the log messages here because this site thinks it "looks like spam"...

Proof that the JSContext instance is created and functions:

```
Aug 17 07:04:55 SpringBoard(TestTweak.dylib)[7402] <Notice>: js test result
```

The only error messages that I can see are the following:

```
Aug 17 07:07:00 MobileSafari(SafariServices)[7464] <Error>: Displaying webpage loading error to user: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=300, networkTaskDescription: (null).
```

```
Aug 17 07:07:00 MobileSafari(WebKit)[7464] <Error>: 0x104fcbc00 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
```

```
Aug 17 07:16:41 runningboardd(RunningBoard)[39] <Notice>: [xpcservice<com.apple.WebKit.Networking>:7504] Error 45 setting darwin role to NonUserInteractive: Operation not supported, falling back to setting priority
```

```
Aug 17 07:16:41 com.apple.WebKit.Networking(CFNetwork)[7504] <Notice>: Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
```

```
Aug 17 07:16:41 com.apple.WebKit.Networking(CFNetwork)[7504] <Notice>: Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
```

None of those error messages explicitly tell me what went wrong.

Why does this work fine when called from a hooked method that belongs to SpringBoard, but not when called from a hooked method that belongs to NSURLSession?

Comment: When you say that you tried calling it asynchronously on the main thread, what did you mean?  The method you’re hooking can be called on any thread, so if you aren’t creating that UIWebView instance on the main thread ahead of time, you probably are going to get a crash.  Just wanted to clarify whether that’s the bit that you’re running asynchronously on the main thread.

Comment: @dgatwood thanks for your reply. What I mean is that I have tried to call `NSLog(@"%@", [myJSContext sharedContext]);` using dispatch_async on the main thread and on the global thread. If I'm not mistaken, this should instantiate the JSContext (if not instantiated yet) and log its pointer from those threads, no? How would I instantiate the JSContext ahead of time so that it's available to NSURLSession methods? Do I use extern? If so, could you please give me an example?

Comment: Hi - you have some funny stuff going on there in that singleton. Sure, the javascript context could be a singleton, but it looks like trouble the way in which you create the UIWebView and then hijack its jscontext. I'm not an expert in what you are trying to do, but I think you need to 1. use WKWebView in stead of course 2. Not have a singleton context but a context relative to the relevant WKWebView. So, for 2, you need to store the relevant webview in a ivar or pass it along as a variable so that you can use that to get the jsContext in your hooked messages.

Comment: Hi @skaak, thanks for your reply. I don't think there is a way to grab the JSContext from a WKWebView, the only method I have found is by using a UIWebView. It works fine when hooking methods from the SpringBoard class, as you can see in my logs, the JavaScript executed successfully, I'm just not sure why it doesn't work in NSURLSession methods. It might be worth noting that I can grab the JavaScriptCore's (ECMAScript) context and execute it in hooked methods from NSURLSession without errors, but as soon as I try to initiate a UIWebView (or WKWebView), it fails to work for unknown reasons.

Comment: Ok - again not my cup of tea but why do you need to capture a jscontext? Why not simply use ```jsCtx = [JSContext alloc] init];```?

Comment: @skaak I mentioned this in my question. I want to have access to the missing JS objects that are present in WebKit, thus I am grabbing the context from a webview. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sorry yes I saw that ...  ```initWithVirtualMachine``` seems the way to go ... I see there is even a ```JSContext.currentContext```.

Comment: @skaak, thanks. Like I said, I have no issues grabbing the ECMAScript implementation directly from JavaScriptCore, however this excludes the objects that I need. I specifically need the JSContext from WebKit.